# Adjust screen size based off user's browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way I can adjust a users screen size once they've visited my website? Basically, If I zoom out of my webpage, my containers and box are off alignment.

So I was wondering there was any way to have like a css or javascript feature to where I'd do something like:

```
if screen size is x, 
then adjust screen size to x
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. One is you can do what the other answer suggested. Or you could go with javascript. Javascript is likely more reliable. You can easily add a window resize event and call a function to adjust your elements. Javascript has a innerHeight and innerWidth so to find the total height or width of your page in pixels. Then just use an if statement. I'm on the phone right now but will pose code later. I will improve this answer if you don't like it. What could also help is if you use percentages in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML5, you can utilize @media in your CSS for this purpose. For example,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px)
{
    div#wrapper
    {
      width: 400px;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 481px)
{
    div#wrapper
    {
      width: 800px;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px)
{
    div#wrapper
    {
      width: 1080px;
    }
}
```

Another way to achieve the same result is to have separate CSS style sheet for each, then you can use the code like this to swap CSS based on the screen size.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="small.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="large.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />
```